# NHibernate Auditing - PostInsert Not Working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My application has the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserLog> Log { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {
        Log = new List<UserLog>();
    }
}

public class UserLog
{
    public virtual int UserLogID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

With the following fluent mappings:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserID);
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        HasMany(x => x.Log)
            .KeyColumn("UserID")
            .OrderBy("DateCreated")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class UserLogMap : ClassMap<UserLog>
{
    public UserLogMap()
    {
        Table("UsersLog");
        Id(x => x.UserLogID);
        References(x => x.User, "UserID");
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
    }
}
```

The UsersLog table simply logs any changes which are made to the User.  I'm trying to hook this up automatically using the NHibernate event listeners.  I have setup my configuration which successfully calls the following 2 methods:

```
public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent @event)
{
    if (@event.Entity is User)
        InsertLog(@event.Entity);
}

public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event)
{
    if (@event.Entity is User)
        InsertLog(@event.Entity);
}
```

Edit (here is the InsertLog method):

```
private void InsertLog(object entity)
{
    var context = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataContext>();
    var user = (User)entity;
    context.Repository<UserLog>().Insert(new UserLog
    {
        User = user,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow
    }); // Insert calls ISession.SaveOrUpdate(entity)
}
```

When i update a record a log is successfully inserted but when i insert a record i get an error telling me the UserID cannot be null in the UsersLog table.  I've played around with a few different variations but nothing seems to work.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me how this can be done.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for the InsertLog() method?

Comment: Hi, i've updated my post with the InsertLog method. It basically grabs my data context (which is a wrapper around the NHibernate Session) and inserts into the repository. Note: I had to use the ServiceLocator and not constructor injection as i had circular reference issue when setting up the data context and nhibernate event listener.

Comment: Is you PK autoincrement? If it is how would NH have the value for it?

Comment: Just a guess...but what about if you were to flush the current session before inserting your UserLog entry? I'm not certain what your context impl looks like, but if you expose a flush operation, I'd try calling that...

Comment: Yeah the PK is set to auto increment. I tried flushing the context but this gave me the error "null id in User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)".  It works if i insert a log entry after inserting a user (without doing a flush) but it seems to have problems inserting the log entry in the PostInsert event.

Comment: Perhaps you can find some guidance in this thread? http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/907d95e9bd381645/11f638b1ad88540c?lnk=gst&q=onpostinsert+identity#11f638b1ad88540c

Comment: Thanks DanP. Calling @event.Session.GetSession(NHibernate.EntityMode.Poco).Save(...) works.  It's abit of a hack i'm willing to go for it for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution posted in question comments.  I simply had to use:

```
@event.Session.GetSession(NHibernate.EntityMode.Poco).Save(...);
```

to save the user instead of accessing the repository.

Comment: Noticed my changes weren't persisting. Explicitly calling Flush() helped as mentioned in the post DanP posted. http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/msg/1b09a4f1583da646

Comment: What is the purpose of the GetSession method? This fixed my problem, but not sure exactly why..

Comment: I'm not sure to tell you the truth. I've just accepted it worked.